# Can a UN employee in the US with a G4 visa open a brokerage account?

Tags: united-states, investing, brokerage

Most brokerage firms ask a prospective client if they're US citizens or permanent residents. Otherwise, they direct customers to an international service which ends up not being helpful.

Comment: A reference on what a G-4 visa is: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/visa-employees-nato.html

Comment: Perhaps I am oversimplifying - You are neither a citizen nor a permanent resident. Therefore you're an international customer. Is there a detail or nuance I am not understanding?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking, and why? The body of your question already seems to answer the title-question ("_Can I open..._") with "_No, it does not seem possible to open an account, because most firms refer you elsewhere_". If you're asking whether _some_ firms will let you, then that becomes a "_Question seeking product, service recommendations..._" which is off-topic. Or are you asking whether there's a law/regulation preventing you opening an account at any firm? If there **isn't** such a law, are you hoping to be able to **force** a broker to open an account?

Comment: @TripeHound I am asking about the laws pertaining to this case. . If I can prove it is Legal for a person described above to open a brokerage account, buy and sell securities and pay appropriate taxes, then I would be able to discuss this with the brokerage firm. Customer service at brokerage firms don't know these details.